# onBackPressed function in android

Tags: android, back

I am creating app, in one class it contains imageview and textview, another contain edittext, when I press back button, the edittext in 2nd class has to store and set it in textview of first class. Here is my code.

BuckMain.java

```
package com.jumoun.ibuck;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BuckMain extends Activity {

    ImageView ivSu;
    TextView tvName;

    private String sSuName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ivSu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivSu);
        tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        ivSu.setClickable(true);

        ivSu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), BuckDisplay.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                sSuName = data.getStringExtra("name");
                tvName.setText(sSuName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BuckDisplay.java

```
    package com.jumoun.ibuck;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BuckDisplay extends Activity {

    ImageView ivSu1;
    TextView tvDisplay;
    TextView tvName1;
    EditText etName1;
    String sName1;

    private int resultCode = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buck_display);
        ivSu1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivSu1);
        tvDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        tvName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName1);
        etName1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        sName1 = etName1.toString();        
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", sName1);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(resultCode, intent);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

When I press back button, it is not showing in first class :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call startActivityForResult

```
ivSu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), BuckDisplay.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
```

And call super after setResult

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("name", etName1.getText().toString());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            sSuName = data.getStringExtra("name");
            tvName.setText(sSuName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The name from the first class still can't be changed yet :(

Comment: should be sSuName = data.getStringExtra("name"); instead of data.getString

Comment: still the same uncle, the tvName can't change it yet :(

Comment: Ok you have to set RESULT_OK let me fix

Comment: There is no need for intent.putExtras(bundle); in onBackPress()

Comment: Still the same uncle, the tvName is still not changing in first class :(

Comment: That because you pass an empty string let me fix the onBackPress()

Comment: It is just a simple application uncle, for practicing but I don't know why it is still not showing :(

Comment: Your onBackPress() is different from my answer. Just copy mine and it should work.